Getting dutch residence permit while I'm working in UK
My partner and I are both working in the Netherlands (We are non-EU citizens) and I'm thinking to leave the Netherlands and work in UK and my partner continue her work in the Netherlands. Can I apply for the partner visa because of her and keep my residence permit while I'm working in UK or not? The main reason is that UK and Netherlands are close and it's possible for us to travel from time to time but We don't want to get visa every 3 months.

With your partner living in the Netherlands I suppose your chance of getting a 5-year multiple-entry visa is very high.  Maintaining a residence permit in the Netherlands when you don't reside in the Netherlands seems a tenuous proposition.
